# How to connect to Informix database using Python Package - ibm_db

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to Informix database using Python package `ibm_db` but am getting the below error.

**Error:**

> builtins.Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL0902C A system error occurred. Subsequent SQL statements cannot be processed. IBM software support reason code: "". SQLSTATE=58005
>   SQLCODE=-902

**Code:**

```
import sys
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pyodbc
import subprocess
import os
import string
import pandas



try:
       conn= ibm_db.connect("HOSTNAME=xxxxxx;PORT=1900;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp ;DATABASE=webrpt; INSTANCE=vec_sandbox;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx","","")

except:
       print ("Transaction couldn't be completed:" , ibm_db.stmt_errormsg())
else:
       print ("Transaction complete.")
```

Comment: I installed the  linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz on the machine.

Now when I am running the Python Program , i am getting this error

[xxxx@xxxx ~]$ python3.6 connect_informix.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_informix.py", line 9, in <module>
    conn= ibm_db.connect("HOSTNAME=xxxxxx;PORT=1900;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp ;DATABASE=xxxx; INSTANCE=vec_sandbox;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxxx","","")
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019 SQLCODE=-1032

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect  using Pyodbc package and installing client SDK on the Linux maching and configuring  /etc/odbc.ini , /etc/odbcinst.ini  and /app/informix/etc/sqlhosts files.

thanks!!!